# Организация виртуального окружения Python внутри контейнера

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Не получается собрать образ контейнера для Python. Выдает ошибку:

```
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh' -c pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r -requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code:127
```

В инете нашел [инструкцию](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbnprYXljM2lqRkVtWUo5UHFKelo2TkRTV3R1UXxBQ3Jtc0tucmJZN3NvcU1tblQ0Q0Q2RkktS1NBdUJRTWJNVDR3alBzU0luZnJoQTdDVXktOW1uTGhqbEY4aTRlNWs4NU9rcXFoTUFQWVY5aFkyRGJ6OV9QRXZhY29Da3Q5bTFLaHhlWlF0SjAwOTRoZThrSkRtcw&q=https%3A%2F%2Fcloud.mail.ru%2Fpublic%2FPFT8%2FGRwLzPvJK&v=eAXjeh5MRVU), нотам написано:

> Создание Flask приложения
> Для начала создадим простое Flask-приложение. Необходимо создать пустой каталог для нашего проекта, в котором будут
> содержаться все файлы проекта. Внутри каталога создать виртуальное окружение и активировать его:

Получается, что в инструкции виртуальное окружение пайтон будет не в контейнере. Как его в контейнер закинуть?

Дoкер же на сколько я понимаю вообще предполагает не установку стороннего софта. А тут получается что на компе должен быть Python.

Docker Python:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV "/venv"

RUN python -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV

ENV PATH "VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ['uwsgi', 'app.ini']
```

Comment: в строке где pip запускается после `&&` ошибка: написано `-m pip …`. `-m` тут лишнее явно.

Comment: @aim, исправил - опечатка была

Comment: По-моему создавать виртуальное окружение внутри контейнера нет смысла. Контейнер и так сам по себе является изолированным окружением, зачем матрёшки городить

Comment: @andreymal, я решил это сделать после того, как проблемы с обновлением pip появились. Я не могу его обновить. Поэтому буду пытаться делать образ под Ubuntu, на нем буду запускать все остальное. Посмотрим, что получится.

Comment: `Дoкер же на сколько я понимаю вообще предполагает не установку стороннего софта` - разрабатывать обысно удобней на локальном хосте (но можно и чисто в докере - просто не так удобно). Нужно понимать зачем вам докер. Одно дело использовать его для разработки, другое дело для сборки артефакта для разворачивания и для запуска.

Comment: @ Roman-Stop RU aggression in UA, для разворачивания и запуска.

Answer (score 0):

в alpine версии не получится надо как минимум ставить slim версию

Comment: Почему? . . . .